# Communication between two database servers

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have 2 databases running on different virtual servers. I have some database processes running on one node. These processes connect to Database Gateway (PG4MQ) and process the messages.

I need to start the process manually. I need to write a script that will monitor the node on which the processes are running and if the node is down or not running then these process will automatically start on the other node.

Can someone tell me is this feasible or not, if feasible then how can this be achieved?

Databases installed on RHEL 5.8. OEM, Grid, DBCA and Oracle Net services are not available.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "database processes". Could you elaborate on exactly what those are?

Comment: The processes are application specific that runs on the database.It is the stored PL/SQL package in the database that is running in a sql session.These functions and procedures in the stored packages connect to PG4MQ and then to IBM webspehere MQ to read the messages o the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Because both of them are virtual servers (you didn't mention the technology used (ESX/KVM...), you can try this:

- Create a small virtual drive that can be mounted on both servers (Linux ? Windows ? - you didn't tell)
- Create a resource checking script (ex. http://howtodba.com/linux-cluster-resource-workers-locking-mechanism/)
- Run the resource checking script, from each box, each 5 minutes (odd minutes on box 1, even minutes on box2).

** The more info you provide, the better solutions you'll get.